# Display 2 images at the same time in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm quite new to iPhone development, and now dealing with a remote control app. Currently I can receive desktop image and perform simple mouse operations. But I still want to show a mouse pointer on my iPhone screen.

The desktop (very big, 1280X800) is in a image view which is the subview of a scroll view. Is there any way I can add a pointer image on top of the desktop image, and set it to any place I want? The pointer image do not receive any user interaction, it would be just floating on the desktop image.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a new UIImageView (or any other UIView subclass) with a frame based on where you want it to appear and add it to the scroll view's view using the [`addSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a) method. By default subviews you add later will appear above subviews you add earlier, but you can explicitly control which view appears on 'top' using 'bringSubviewToFront:'.